# data binding with fragment error cannot find BindingImpl class

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have been struggling with this error for hours and tried most of the solutions I found but no luck

I made sure of

- Layout is the outermost tag
- enabled data binding
- spelling mistakes in xml
- set the view model in the fragment class
- and of course invalidate cache and restart

`import com.linguistic.linguistic.databinding.FragmentAddNewConversationBindingImpl; ^ symbol:   class FragmentAddNewConversationBindingImpl` 
This error only appears when I use the viewmodel in the xml call
My xml:
You will find me using viewModel in the first radio button

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.linguistic.linguistic.learnerscreens.ui.addconversation.AddNewConversationViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".learnerscreens.ui.addconversation.AddNewConversationFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/register_field_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/bottomSheetDialogHeader"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="@string/add_conversation_dialog_title"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_close"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_close" />

            <com.linguistic.linguistic.utils.ui.LinguisticRadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_select_address"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                <com.linguistic.linguistic.utils.ui.RadioLinguisticButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_new_native"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.languageName}"

                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_gray_user"
                    app:iconColor="@color/buttom_toggle_icon_selector"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:secondaryText="@string/currently_available"
                    app:textMainAppearance="@style/ToggleButtonText.ToggleButtonMainText"
                    app:textSecondaryAppearance="@style/ToggleButtonText.ToggleButtonSecondaryText" />
            </com.linguistic.linguistic.utils.ui.LinguisticRadioGroup>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_select_address"
                style="@style/bottomDialogSheetMainButton"
                android:background="@drawable/top_bottom_gradient"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:text="@string/start_chatting"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

My ViewModel class

```kotlin
package com.linguistic.linguistic.learnerscreens.ui.addconversation

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.linguistic.linguistic.LinguisticApplication
import com.linguistic.linguistic.data.models.AvailablePartners
import com.linguistic.linguistic.repository.LearnerRepository
import com.linguistic.linguistic.utils.getLanguageName
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class AddNewConversationViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val languageName = MutableLiveData(getLanguageName(LinguisticApplication.getNativeLanguageID()!!))

    val availablePartnersLiveData = liveData<AvailablePartners> {
        LearnerRepository.getAvailablePartnerCounts(
            LinguisticApplication.getNativeLanguageID()!!,
            LinguisticApplication.getLearningLanguageID()!!)
    }
}
```

My FragmentClass

```kotlin
package com.linguistic.linguistic.learnerscreens.ui.addconversation
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.linguistic.linguistic.databinding.FragmentAddNewConversationBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.linguistic_toggle_button.view.*
class AddNewConversationFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddNewConversationBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: AddNewConversationViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddNewConversationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddNewConversationViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
      
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.apollo'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apollo {
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.linguistic.linguistic"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    testCompileOnly "org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tip the variable when you send it through data binding.

In your ViewModel the variable ***languageName*** is a mutableLiveData but doesn't have a tip, then you need to tip it.

Your code:

```
 val languageName = MutableLiveData(getLanguageName(LinguisticApplication.getNativeLanguageID()!!))
```

Code to replace:

```
 val languageName : String = MutableLiveData(getLanguageName(LinguisticApplication.getNativeLanguageID()!!))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to rebuild the project:

[image]